# Glib 2.39.2 error when compiling on Cygwin

Tags: compilation, cygwin, cross-compiling, glib

I'm compiling glib 2.39.2 on Cygwin (as part of a home project I'm doing => trying to get my usual unix setup (minus a couple of things) running on cygwin) and am hitting a rather strange error. I don't want to modify the glib source (I honestly like the Arch approach of vanilla patches), but I don't see how else I could fix it.

I ran `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --with-prce=internal --disable-debug --disable-gtk-doc`, followed by `make -j4`.

The output can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/8XtbrtaP) (autogen ran fine, if you want it's output, just ask)

The error is in line 507 of gcharset.c, at `char *locale = g_win32_getlocale ();`.
It complains that it's an implicit declaration and that you can't make a pointer from an integer without a cast.

Comment: "I don't want to modify the glib source" and fixing this may be mutually exclusive.  2.39.x are unstable development releases, and Windows support sometimes gets neglected until later in development cycle.  If you absolutely must use the unstable version you could try git to see if this issue is fixed (and, if not, submit a bug report)... otherwise, you may want to use the latest *stable* release (2.38.x).

Comment: I have the same error in 2.38.2, so  it's part of the actual glib library. I'm using the unstable one since that doesn't usually break anything, but lets me use latest gtk3.

Comment: Patches are often necessary for Cygwin, and the patches in the Cygwin glib2.0 package are there for a reason.  Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Yaakov current Cygwin glib2 package is outdated; and I'm too used to having new(est?) compiled, after using arch so long. I'm trying to find the Cygwin patches right now.

Comment: My target for the x86_64 rebuild has been (where I have had a choice) what was very stable when I started, e.g. GNOME 3.8, KDE 4.10, MATE 1.6, Xfce 4.10, Perl 5.14, Python 2.7/3.2, etc.  That rebuild is mostly complete now, so I should be ready to consider GNOME 3.10 and KDE 4.11 relatively soon.  In the meantime, do keep in mind that Fedora 20 (GNOME 3.10) went stable just days ago.

Comment: Any chance you could show me the patches for glib/glibc, X and similar? I'd be interested in developing Cygwin (as much as my schedule allows) to make it into a full POSIX-compliant subsystem. That was pretty much what I set out to do (though that's slightly unrelated to this question)